# Script com Erro mv: cannot move novo_nome to novo_nome/nome_original Directory not empty

Tags: linux, bash, centos, linha-de-comando

Olá, tenho a seguinte função abaixo, o objetivo dela é verificar se a pasta existe, e **excluir**, **extrair** o arquivo `.tar.gz` e **renomear**.

```bash
ssl_v="1.0.2g"
ABI="armv6"
# Clean then Unzip
[ -d openssl-${ssl_v} ] && rm -fr openssl-${ssl_v}
tar xf openssl-${ssl_v}.tar.gz
[ -d openssl-${ssl_v} ] && mv openssl-${ssl_v} openssl-${ssl_v}-${ABI}
```

Porem estou recebendo o seguinte erro:

> mv: cannot move ‘openssl-1.0.2g’ to
>   ‘openssl-1.0.2g-armv6/openssl-1.0.2g’: Directory not empty

Ou seja, ele está criando uma nova pasta(`openssl-1.0.2g`) dentro da que deveria ser deletada(`openssl-1.0.2g-armv6`).

Quando não existem pastas a serem deletadas, tudo funciona perfeitamente, não tenho certeza se algum código está de forma errada, *como posso resolver isso*?

Comment: Também tentei com ```mv openssl-${ssl_v} openssl-${ssl_v}-${ABI}```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Não existia nenhum comando para deletar a pasta `openssl-1.0.2g-armv6` por isso estava dando erro.

```
# Clean then Unzip
[ -d openssl-${ssl_v} ] && rm -fr openssl-${ssl_v}
[ -d openssl-${ssl_v}-${ABI} ] && rm -fr openssl-${ssl_v}-${ABI}
tar xf openssl-${ssl_v}.tar.gz
[ -d openssl-${ssl_v} ] && mv openssl-${ssl_v} openssl-${ssl_v}-${ABI}
```